# Python, find specified file in folder

Tags: python, file, find

What is wrong in this code? I want to find a specified file in folder. Thansk for your help.

```
import os, fnmatch

def find(root, mask): //Error
    files_list = os.listdir(os.path.abspath(root))
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files_list, mask):
        yield filename

def test():
    res = find ('D:\\Sample\\', 'hallo.txt') 

test()
```

the error:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last): def find(root, mask): NoneType
```

Comment: What is `os.dir` supposed to be?

Comment: So do you get any errors, or what is your problem with the code?

Comment: @sth: I am sorry, I did not write the error code :-)

Comment: The actual error message is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), it will yield filenames one by one. You can call `list` on `res` if you want a list of all matches:

```
list_of_matches = list(res)
```

Also your default argument of `root=os.dir` makes no sense. Maybe use `'.'`?

Comment: If he only wants the first, and possibly only, match, use `match = next(find ('D:\\Sample\\', 'hallo.txt'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Some indentation missing for the test function

```
def test ():
    res = find ('D:\\Sample\\', 'hallo.txt')
```